# Python dictionary to get multiple keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a problem when I try to get more than one key in a dictionary.

```
mattan = {'name':'Mattan', 'height':70, 'shoe size':10.5,'hair':'Brown','eyes':'Brown'}
keys = ['name','height','hair']
for key in keys:
    mattan.get(key)
```

I want to get that three argument but it doesn´t work. Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a better description of what you want to do and what happens instead. What do you mean by "get that three argument", and in how far did it not work? Do you get an error? Do you get only one out of three keys? Note that the code as shown discards the values it looks up; there is no difference to getting one or all keys in this case.

Comment: simplest possible case: maybe you just wanted `print(mattan.get(key))` in the last line?

Comment: yeah, I dind´t print it :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
for key in set(mattan.keys()).intersection(set(keys)):
    print(mattan[key])
```

or

```
for key in set(mattan.keys()).intersection(set(keys)):
        print(mattan.get(key))
```

To print all the values that have keys in the keys list and are in the key of the dictionary.

Comment: In how far does this address the question? The keys are all in the dictionary.